# Is there another part number for z1w47 SMT zener diode?

Tags: diodes, components, surface-mount

So I need to replace a SMT component that burnt on a board. The part number that I was able to get from the component is Z1W47. A quick google search lead me to CZ1W47. However, I can't find anyone selling this zener diode with this part number. Is there another known or alternate component under a different part number to replace this bad one? Thank you!

Comment: If you have the datasheet of the original one should be easy to find one with similar or superior relevant specs: package, power dissipation, working voltage, tolerance, and so on, depending on the application.

Comment: [Datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/674679/ContinentalDeviceIndiaLimited/CZ1W47/1) says "Equivalent to 1W 1N47XX Series".

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I just can't find a similar component to the one I need. I keep finding components like this one http://www.cdil.com/diodes/copy-of-1n52xxb-series-500mw that supposedly is a replacement for the SMT, but it's not. If anyone knows of an actual part number or link to a website where I can buy one that would be great. Thank you